# Best approach for user-placeable custom UIViews?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm consider the following **usage scenario**:

1. The user adds a new shape to a page
2. He or she places the shape freely on the current view (e.g. using a pan gesture)
3. Also, the user can resize the shape (e.g. using a pinch gesture on it)
4. The shape snaps to already existing shapes on the drawing

**Implementation details:** A page is a custom UIView. The user can add as many shapes as he or she likes. Shapes are instances of different custom UIViews which needs to adapt their content to the new size (see step 3). Overlapping shapes are not possible. And the user must be able to select shapes for operations like "remove".

**Question:**

I could simply instantiate the shape UIViews and add them as subview to the page UIView. But then I would need to implement all the details like tracking touches to move UIViews to new positions, running the collision detection, handle resize and so on.

Are there controls/classes/... in UIKit, CoreGraphics or the like available which would make my life easier?

I found `UIDynamicBehaviors` in UIKit. Would this is be way to go or would you suggest a different approach?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: There may be libs out there that help you, asking for those is off-topic. Just do the tap handling yourself, it is not that hard and you may learn something about how views and touches are handled by UIKit.

Comment: Attach a pan gesture recognizer to each view and then implement view dragging. As Luk says, it's not that hard.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. If this is the way to go, than I will give it a try.